# How can I install deb packages on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: software-installation

When I used 16.04/10 deb packages worked and installed, even when I upgraded to 17. Now I've burnt a downloaded 17.04 image from the public Ubuntu servers nothing installs with software center.

I used to have a list of PPAs and repos and other sources and now that's vanished.

So, my question is how on earth do installs work now as opposed to on 16 and earlier?

Comment: When you do an upgrade, it disables all third party ppas and repos, so that it doesn't interfere with the upgrade. You have to manually go back and re-enable them in the `Software & Updates` application, "Other Software" tab. I also recommend that if it's not already there, install `gdebi` and make it the default installer for .deb files. Much easier than Software Center to install stuff.

Comment: What do you mean by "burned a downloaded image?" Do you mean you made a fresh installation? You said "even when I upgraded to 17" meaning things worked fine when you upgraded?

Answer (score 0):

sudo dpkg -i [some deb file]

This will install a deb.

If you are trying to install packages try using *apt-get*. E.g.  sudo apt-get install   postresql
Use apt-cache to search for packages, etc.

Comment: so Svetlana it is not clear what is going on; when you say "now i burnt a downloaded 17.04 image" ... I am thinking you are using what we call a live version; .... burnt onto maybe DVD .. as you say you have already upgraded to 17 ... you can't install packages onto a live CD or DVD version; so help us understand what you have done; s

Comment: @pdc please comment on the question. OP will not be notified about the comment you've written here which seems out of place, unless she's already written a comment here (and deleted it, since I don't see one)